# FB.login not working in mobile browsers

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is not native solution, just responsive web site.. The problem is, that FB.login simply doesn't do anything. The same goes for FB.ui methods..

i call fb init in head (but also tried in body with same results..) like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({ 
    appId: '{$app_id}',
    status: true, 
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    channelUrl: 'https://www.nottyfly.com/channel.php',
    oauth: true
});
```

When user clicks fb login button, the code is like this:

```
function fbLogin(){ 
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
            var perms = response.data[0];
            document.getElementById("accesstoken").value=FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
            document.getElementById("korak1").submit();                                          
            } );
      } else {
            alert('{$alert_confirm_app}');
      }
  }, {scope:'email'});  
}
```

This all work great at web pages, but on mobile browsers produces nothing?

ps. Here is demo [web page](http://www.nottyfly.com/manage/public/?page=promotion&type=webpoints&noredirect=1&p=559a7de99a964)

Comment: Your demo page worked fine for me in Safari (iOS), the default Android browser and Chrome. Is the problem only happening on some browsers?

Comment: It happens is somebody sends this link via facebook messenger app. When user clicks on link it stays in messebger app, where facebook login button doesn't work. If i open link in safari it works. How to deal with this problem?

Comment: so, it does not work in facebook In-App Browser... i cant ask users to swith to normal browser :(

Answer (score 1):

This is common issue among mobile browsers and you will find that it would also be in some android devices.

For precaution it is under best practice to build flow of login manually. Go here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

So yes, you will need to go with manual integration. But, it will be full-proof integration without doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I may be late, but I just want to help anyone who happens to get stuck here.

Whenever access is coming from the Facebook Mobile Browsers. Clicking FB.login does nothing because it already assumes you're logged in. What you need to do is use the current accessToken and userID of the logged in account to get the details that you need using FB's API.

Here's a code sample from Javascript:

```
signInWithFB(): void {
FB.getLoginStatus((response: any) => {
  if (response.status !== 'connected') {
    return FB.login((response: any) => {
      this.handleResponse(response)
    }, {
      scope: 'public_profile,email',
      enable_profile_selector: true,
      auth_type: 'rerequest',
      return_scopes: true
    });
  } else {
    this.handleResponse(response)
  }
});
}

handleResponse(response) {
FB.api(`/me?fields=email,picture,first_name,last_name`,
  (response: any) => {
    this._loginService.socialLogin({
      email: response.email ? response.email : '',
      profilePicture: {
        'url': response.picture.data.url,
        'key': ''
      },
      fullName: `${response.firstName} ${response.lastName}`,
      socialId: response.id,
      ...FACEBOOK_LOGIN
    }).
      subscribe(res => {
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: doesnt work, at least for me, getting status unknown

Comment: Yeah, I had to do the manual verification instead of this solution, for some reason, it doesn't work anymore.