# Facebook SDK for JavaScript does not work for mobile browsers

Tags: android, angular, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing a web application that is using Facebook SDK for Javascript for allowing Facebook authentication. The has been built using Angular 5. The authentication is working for web browsers but it does not work for any mobile browsers on Android. Methods such as FB.getLoginStatus  and FB.login simply do not run. It seems to be a known issue among mobile browsers but I have not found a way to work around. Any ideas about what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you link to the known issue that we can see where we are

Comment: Hi @SimonFranzen, I found this tread stating that idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248610/fb-login-not-working-in-mobile-browsers . It is a poor explanation but made me think it is actually a fact.